# How can I update LinkedIn Basic profile in Python

Tags: python, rest, linkedin-api, rest.li

I am trying to update LinkedIn profile using this Python code :-

```
import requests
access_token = "xxx"
profile_id = "me"  # "me" refers to the currently authenticated user's profile
new_headline = "New Headline Text"
new_summary = "New Summary Text"


def update_profile():
    
    endpoint_url = f"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    payload = {
        "headline": new_headline,
        "summary": new_summary
    }
    response = requests.patch(endpoint_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Profile updated successfully.")
    else:
        print("Error updating profile.")
        print(response.text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_profile()
```

The authorisations I have are :-

[image]

But I get this error :-

```
"message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.linkedin.restli.common.HttpMethod.PATCH",
```

How to fix this error ?

This is my Python environment

[image]

Comment: Maybe this has some tips  https://github.com/linkedin-developers/linkedin-api-python-client/blob/main/examples/crud_ad_accounts.py

Comment: Maybe need w_compliance permission from LinkedIn ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the endpoint you're trying to reach, https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me, state in the documentation it prefers a requests.patch() method?

Also, make sure that you're authenticating. You'll have to retrieve a token from the OAuth2 process, via your app, and provide as part of the the headers of the headers argument of your requests.post|put|patch() method.

Answer (score 1):

- LinkedIn permits partial updates, thus you will only be able to utilise `POST` requests and pass objects with the key `patch` within them.
- Please read through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-edit-api/positions#partial-update)
- The format of the request url looks like this :

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/id={person ID}/positions/{position ID}
```

- If you wish to use the API to update the data, you would supply a `patch` object that contains a `$set` object.

```
{
  "patch": {
    "$set": {
      "endMonthYear": {
        "month": 1,
        "year": 2016
      }
    }
  }
}
```